# Is there a way to set a default controller param in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a chess game. Whenever I create the game, I am passing a "name" parameter to my create controller, but I also want the white_player_id to always set itself to the current_user.email. Is there a way to pass the email as a default param to the white_player_id? This is what I've tried so far:

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController
      def create
        @game = current_user.games.create(game_params)
      end  

      def game_params
        params.required(:game).permit(:name).with_defaults(white_player_id: current_user.email)
      end
```

However with this method, the white_player_id is always set to 0 instead of the user email. Is my syntax incorrect, or will this not work?

Comment: Shouldn't you pass `current_user.id` as the `white_player_id`?  Or is your `white_player_id` column a string column to store emails?

Comment: Because of how we have the DB set up right now, there isn't an id field in the user table. I'm going to discuss the need for adding an id field on Wednesday, but for now I need a way to populate the white_player_id field for the game table with the user email.

Comment: But what type of column is `white_player_id` on the database? it looks like you are trying to save a string on an integer column, if the columns is an integer rails will call `to_i` on the value to convert it to an integer.

Comment: Oh goodness I think you just solved the issue. Duh. Wasn't even thinking about types, no wonder it wouldn't store properly. That was my issue, thanks for helping!

Comment: Can you share your schema.rb and your models relevant to this controller i.e. game, player?

Comment: Ariel I deleted my answer so you can answer it =]